# MVC 3: Javascript After client side validation event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I need to convert client side validation errors (class="field-validation-error") to tooltip.
This is not a problem with some jQuery tricks!

But I need to execute this conversion after client side validation.
I do not know if exist a "validate" event on the form or on the single field.

this is a client side validation triggered while typing (not while submission) then I need an event that is fired when the field value changed.

The best is the same event that change (Using standard MVC client validation) the class of the "input" to "input-validation-error".

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this will help but try this code:

```
var currentValidate = Sys.Mvc.FormContext.prototype.validate;

var newValidate = function(eventName) {
   var result = currentValidate.call(this, eventName);
   // Perform post-validation logic here
   return result;
};

Sys.Mvc.FormContext.prototype.validate = newValidate;
```

Comment: This looks just what I am after - what script do I need to include to get access to the Sys.Mvc namespace? I am currently getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined"